# Type 'SafeResourceUrl' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf-viewer

I am trying to sanitize a pdf url and want to assign it to a string type variable so that I can use it for pdf viewer. Is there any way to do that? 
If I use `any` type for pdfSrc type, I am getting `Invalid parameter object: need either .data, .range or .url in the <pdf-viewer>`.

**Note:** The URL which I used is for reference purpose, i would use external URLs in that place

**landingpage.component.ts**

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class LandingpageComponent implements OnInit {
     public pdfSrc: string;
}

constructor(    
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
}

fnOpenAsset() {     
   let url = 'http://localhost/pdf_viewer-master/18/docs/pdf.pdf';
   this.pdfSrc = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
}
```

**landingpage.component.html**

```
<pdf-viewer class="alignComponentCenter" [src]="pdfSrc" 
</pdf-viewer>
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I got a way to fix this. I tried sanitizing the SafeResourceUrl again with `sanitize()` method whose return value is string | null.

In case you want to use `bypassSecurityTrustUrl()`, then `SecurityContext.URL` will take place. In my case I used `SecurityContext.RESOURCE_URL`

```
export class LandingpageComponent implements OnInit {
     public pdfSrc: string;
}

constructor(    
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
}

fnOpenAsset() {     
   let url = 'http://localhost/pdf_viewer-master/18/docs/pdf.pdf';
   this.pdfSrc = this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.RESOURCE_URL, this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url));
}
```

Comment: Is this in any sort better than to assume that as `SafeResourceUrl` is a `string` ? _using the `as string`_

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested, you can just remove the variable declaration (or declare `any` type), but I doubt many would agree to be the correct solution.

The various Dom sanitizer methods don't return strings, they return various object types.

See the official API docs: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

```
this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
```

Returns a `SafeResourceUrl` type object, not a string; so your declaration should reflect this rather than the nebulous `any` type.

Comment: if I use ```any``` type, I am getting  ```Invalid parameter object: need either .data, .range or .url``` in the ```<pdf-viewer>``` That's y i want to make that as string. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

### Future solution

There are efforts from the angular team to make the usage of `Safe*` types more flexible. As far as I understand [issue #33028](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/33028) on the angular github page they are currently enabling the direct use of `Safe*` types as `string`. That way you could be using `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl()` and directly assign the return value to the `src` property. Excactly as @Muthu tried it initially.

> `this.pdfSrc = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);`

This would affect the following types (as they all extend the `SafeValue` interface):

- `SafeHtml`
- `SafeUrl`
- `SafeResourceUrl`
- `SafeScript`
- `SafeStyle`

### Current solution

For now it seems like the best workaround to access the actual string is to re-sanitize the `Safe*` value, just like @Muthu points it out in his accepted answer.

Alternatively one can either use `any` type or force the return value to be a string by using `as string` after calling the function. Note that this only works for certain scenarios, e.g. assigning HTML code from `SafeHtml`.

```
let html: any = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("<h1>just some html!</h1>");
let html2: string = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("<h1>even more html!</h1>") as string;
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually solved my problem of unable to assign `SafeResourceUrl` to a `string`

Here is the solution of my. However, I am not sure if this will cause some security problem, I am using this code for my small project, I am open for any criticism and improvement.

```
dir: SafeResourceUrl;

downloadLink.href = this.dir['changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity'];
```

Why `'changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity'`?

When you console.log the `dir` which has the type of `SafeResourceUrl`, you will see this `changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity` property exist in it, and it consist of the blob link you need.

Answer (score -2):

Just keep `public pdfSrc` without any type. It will automatically cast the required type.

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

public pdfSrc;

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
}

fnOpenAsset() {     
   let url = 'http://localhost/pdf_viewer-master/18/docs/pdf.pdf';
   this.pdfSrc = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
}
```